# While loop in Matlab will not compare strings

Tags: excel, matlab, while-loop, increment

I have designed a while loop in Matlab to do a specific task. Firstly, I am importing the titles of several columns of an excel spreadsheet.

```
'student #' ' assn1'    ' assn2'    ' assn3'    ' assn4'    ' assn5'    ' lab1' ' lab2' ' lab3' ' lab4' ' midterm'  ' final exam'
```

These are stored in a matrix called 'txt'. While my counter variable 'i' has not reached the numerical value equal to the size of 'txt', enter the loop. I store the current value of the vector in the variable j.If the first 4 letters of this value are equal to "assn", increase the assignmentCounter by 1. If it is not, do nothing. Then, before exiting the loop, increase the counter variable 'i' by 1. Ideally, this program should tell me how many times an assn appears in the matrix 'txt'. However, my end result is that the assignmentCounter is 0. I do not know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!
Code:

```
%Assignment 4
clear;
clc;
filename = 'marksdata.xlsx';
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread(filename);

%Loop through the categories
assignmentCounter = 0;
categorySize = size(txt);
i = 1;
loopCount = 0;
while i < categorySize
         j = txt(i, categorySize);
         if strncmpi('assn',j, 4)
             assignmentCounter = assignmentCounter + 1;   
         end
         i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: One thing off the bat is that size() returns a vector [rows, cols]. Depending on whether you want `categorySize` to be the number of rows or columns in `txt`, you should do `[categorySize, ~] = size(txt)` or `[~, categorySize] = size(txt)` respectively.

Comment: You should really learn to use the debugger in Matlab. Just set a breakpoint and then you can see the values of your variables. This will help you to debug an issue like this very quickly.

Comment: Also, your example strings at the top of your question contain leading spaces. Is this the case in your actual data? If it is, then it should be obvious why comparing the first 4 characters to `'assn'` won't match anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, this program should tell me how many times an assn appears in
>   the matrix 'txt'.

If that is all what you want, this why not:

```
txt={'student #' ' assn1'    ' assn2'    ' assn3'    ' assn4'    ' assn5'    ' lab1' ' lab2' ' lab3' ' lab4' ' midterm'  ' final exam'}
c=strfind(txt,'assn');
sum(~cellfun(@isempty,c))
%  5
```

so `assn` shows up 5 times.

Comment: Nice. Of course if the OP wants to check for occurrences at the start of the string only, then `c=regexpi(txt,'^ assn')` would work (accounting for the leading space). In this case, the `cellfun` could be replaced with `sum([c{:}])`, but perhaps less readable.